# can anyone tell me please why are these number are concatenating,

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner at programming, i always stumble upon this problem whenever i am trying to add numbers, instead of adding, it concatenates. Please someone explain what is happening here and some solutions so that i would not come across these type of problems again thanks ^^

```
function add(x,n) {
let result = x + n;
return result;
}

let x = prompt();
let n = prompt();

alert ( add(x,n) );
```

if i have x=5 and n=2 it should alert 7, but it shows 52. however if i use different arithmetic operators, it works. if i use -, it subtracts.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `prompt` is returning a string. `x` is `"5"` and `n` is `"2"` (not `5` and `2`).

One option is to use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert these values to integers.

```js
function add(x, n) {
  let result = parseInt(x) + parseInt(n);
  return result;
}

let x = prompt();
let n = prompt();

alert(add(x, n));
```